# What algorithm can I use to count steps using Accelerometer and Gyroscope?

Tags: accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope, pedometer

I need to count steps using data from Accelerometer and Gyroscope from a cellphone.

What algorithm can I use considering I have these data? Where my Accelerometer describes the velocity of the device, but don't include gravity. Example: (x: 0.3, y: -1.2, z: 0.2). And Gyroscope describes the rotation of the device. Example: (x: 0.0, y: -0.1, z: -0.1).

I can get these data every 1 millisecond.

I tried this approach but it didn't work well: https://programmerworld.co/android/how-to-create-walking-step-counter-app-using-accelerometer-sensor-and-shared-preference-in-android/

Pedometer plugins don't work for me, because I need to calculate the time for each step.

Comment: Record the data when you are walking, running, standing and sitting.  See what the differences you can look for are.  Also giving examples of 0,0,0 are really not helpful in knowing what units they are.  If the velocity is gravity adjusted it is probably not measuring versus the orientation of the device and you don't need the gyro.

Comment: Sorry, I put an example of the values when I was walking.